# sublime text option "-n -w" (for git) always open my previous tabs

Tags: git, sublimetext3, git-commit

I have the folling command set for my commits in git under windows using git bash:

```
core.editor='c:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\subl' -w -n
```

I would like to enter the commit window in a new separate window. That part works fine.

The problem hower is that whenever I commit something and that sumblime window opens, it also opens a 2nd window with all the tabs that I am currently working on (unless sublime was open already anyway). When there is currently no sublime text window open and I commit something, two windows instead of just one open.

How can I prevent sublime from openening the other window (with my previous tabs) too **and at the same time** when I open sublime normally (e.g. from the task bar or start menu), that all my previously open tabs will show up?

I know I can set these options:

```
"hot_exit": false,
"remember_open_files": false
```

Bu that will disable remembering the open tabs globally and not just for the context of git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a portable version of Sublime Text as Git editor.

So your installed version will stay with your files and will not be opened by Git.

If you want to use the same plugins and settings then just make simbolic links to some folders in portable version "Data" folder:

```
c:\Sublime Text 3 Portable\Data\Installed Packages\  -->  c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\
c:\Sublime Text 3 Portable\Data\Packages\            -->  c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\
```

Do not link "Local" folder because it contains your local session data.